# How to extract symbols from an elisp buffer?

Tags: variables, symbols

While I could parse the elisp myself, is there a way to extract symbols from an elisp buffer?

That is, variable names, macros & functions - not part of strings.

Comment: The built-in library `imenu` does this in a few different ways; e.g., a separate buffer, or in the menu-bar, or in the pop-up context menu.  There are different ways to sort ... Perhaps you can use that library to generate the lists you seek ....

Comment: Here is a link to a gist containing a couple of functions that I use to comb through a buffer containing Lisp stuff in order to extract a list of all symbols and to tell me whether they have been defined.  You apparently need only a portion of that functionality, but it may give you a head-start when creating your own custom function(s):  https://gist.github.com/lawlist/af7b837436688d84124784a372bde5d4  Sample usage:  evaluate the gist, open up a Lisp file such as `simple.el` and type `M-x is-it-defined`